# The default Firebase app has not yet been configured but FirebaseApp.configure() added to appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I am trying to configure the firebase cloud messaging on my ios App.
As per instruction of Firebase docs, I have added firebase configuration like this (appdelegate.swift)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: { _, _ in }
    )
} else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
    } else if let token = token {
        self.fcmId = token
        print("\n My FCM registration token: \(token) \n")
    }
}

FirebaseApp.configure()

//For check update
Siren.shared.wail()

if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "login") as? String == "yes" {
    
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}else{
    
    let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goToLogin") as! LoginViewController
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
return true
```

}

when I run the app on iPhone 6, I am getting.

[Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` to your application initialization. This can be done in in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`(or the`@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI).

Answer (score 0):

Move `FirebaseApp.configure()` at the top, as this should be called first before calling any Firebase method.

Comment: now I am getting

 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '454886066833'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

Comment: Have you added the Push Notification capability in the Signing & Capabilities tab of your project target in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, In Background Modes,  remote notifications is selected

Comment: Ok, then you should set APNS device token before retrieving FCM Token, as stated by the error itself.

Comment: Yes I have already added

` func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        
        let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: dataDict
        )
    }
    `

Comment: Did you have set `Messaging.messaging().apnsToken` in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method?

Comment: yes

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234850/discussion-between-sarvajeet-singh-and-information-tech-support).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I'm writing this because I was struggling with this also.

I had an `init()` in the view that opens as a default view that fetched data from `FireBase`, and basically, it called that init before calling the `FireBase` configuration function and it caused that error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it looks like there isn't the right solution yet.

Sometimes it doesn't help to just put `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the top of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Just place your `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the `init()` of the AppDelegate.

So you can be sure that Firebase will be configured first.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used GeoFire as a CocoaPods dependency while the other Firebase libraries were added using Swift package manager.
Moving all to CocoaPods fixed the issue.

I wish GeoFire worked on Swift package manager alongside with Firebase libraries. I had to stick with CocoaPods.